# Rubik's cube image rights EU court decision

Tags: software, licensing, european-union, human-rights

In February 2016, I have asked a question ([Rubik's cube image rights](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6923/rubiks-cube-image-rights)) regarding image rights of Rubik's Cube. In short - I have developed an Android application allowing user to solve Rubik's Cube, but Rubik's Brand Ltd. (https://www.rubiksbrand.com) refused me to publish it at that time.

Time passed, and recently, I have found that EU court decided that Rubik's Cube shape is not a trademark:

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-37938454

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/news/rubiks-cube-shape-not-trademark-patent-eu-court-battle-a7410141.html

My question then is - can I now safely publish my application on Google Play?
I am not a lawyer, so please be patient with me if I am asking nonsense. :-)

Comment: the "Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship."

Comment: @Refineo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education - "Education is the process of facilitating learning, or the acquisition of **knowledge**, skills, values, beliefs, and habits."  I do not seek advice from qualified legal practitioner, if I was, I would contact qualified legal practitioner. I do not expect any liability from authors of the answers. My application was written as open source, and would be available for free, I am not building a business. Please keep it helpful, thanks.

Comment: The case is Simba Toys GmbH & Co. KG v. EUIPO, C-30/15 P.  http://curia.europa.eu/juris/documents.jsf?num=C-30/15

Comment: You're asking for legal advice about your specific situation. That's the definition of specific legal advice. Off-topic completely: *"Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter."*

Comment: @Nij Umm.. when you look at current questions on this site, could you tell me which ones are not specific? How can I not ask specific question? Can I even ask a question? I thought that people are here to help each other, rather than tell what they can and can't ask.

Comment: @Refineo Thank you! I will look at it. Still, some explanation would be probably helpful :D

Comment: @Nij Btw, https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask says: "be specific"

Comment: @Firzen as you asked "can I now safely publish my application on (...)" this suggested you seek specific legal advice. Maybe you could rephrase? What kind of explanation are you looking for?

Comment: @Refineo I would be thankful for explanation of that court decision you send for example. I am looking at it, but it is very long, and I just don't understand it. I understand that I could have asked a lawyer and pay for their advice, but I thought that getting free advice from others is the whole point of stackexchange, is it not?  https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Clearly says that questions regarding "Statutes or court decisions" are welcome here, and I do ask about the recent EU court decision and how it affects my application. I don't know how more specific I could be.

Comment: Yes, be specific about the details of the question, because vagueness doesn't help. That doesn't make questions asking for specific legal advice acceptable, and twisting words to try defending an off-topic question simply isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unanswerable. You can read the ruling [here](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=185244&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=873557), and if there's something that you don't understand you can pose a factual question that someone might be able to answer. If you were wondering if the lower court's decision was overturned, yes, it was. If you are wondering what Article [7(1)(e)(ii) of Regulation No 40/94](https://wipolex.wipo.int/en/text/126861) is, we might be able to explain that. It is impossible to say whether a particular action is legally safe, at least not here. There is more to IP law than trademark.

In fact the point of SE is to give free *factual information*, and not advise people what they should or can safely do. That is the line that can't be crossed: it would be illegal to give you legal advice.